# ui-view wont render nested content

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I've linked my plnkr here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kuyw1shiKwz9wzVmoo5K?p=preview

On the addProducts tab, I want to load the nested states in the ui-view.

```
.state("productEdit", {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/products/edit/:productId",
      templateUrl: "productEditView.html",
      controller: "ProductEditCtrl as vm",
      resolve: {
        productResource: "productResource",
        product: function(productResource, $stateParams){
          var productId = $stateParams.productId;
          return productResource.get({productId: productId}).$promise;
        }
      }
    })
    .state("productEdit.info",{
      url:"/info",
      templateURL: "productEditInfoView.html"
    })
    .state("productEdit.price",{
      url:"/price",
      templateURL: "productEditPriceView.html"
    })
```

ProductEditInfoView.html has a form with some controls, which I expect to load in the ProductEditView page, but they are not visible

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are case sensitive. Change `templateURL` to `templateUrl` and you should be good to go.